# Enter number in reverse order in text field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs, typescript, react-native

I have a TextInput in react-native , I want to enter a number in order as 0.00 => 0.01 => 0.12 => 1.23 => 12.34 => 123.45 like this on each change text . CSS Direction "rtl" is not working . Looking for an algorithm to apply in my JS file for react-native textInput on

```
onChangeText={(amount) => this.onChangeText(amount)}

 onChangeText = (amount) => {
    //. Logic for reverse goes here

    this.setState({
      amount: newAmount,
      amountError: false,
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an input mask. You can write by yourself or implement the npm package `react-text-mask` into your project. Take the following example, you can twist it to match what you're looking for, which is quite similar.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-currency-input-with-react-text-mask-4es23?from-embed=&file=/package.json:249-264

Comment: yes mask input is a good way, but it is not adding in reverse order with decimals as 0.01. => 0.12 and so one. But like the answer though